# Is it legal to allocate the amount of memory for array of characters and fill it from the end?

Tags: c, string, memory-management

I've done an experiment recently and after that I was wondering whether I balanced on the edge of the undefined behavior, because gcc didn't scream - but without flags, gcc can swallow much horror.

I have two arrays and want to write one of them in the reversed order.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_SEQ 256

char* regular_sequence = malloc(MAX_SEQ);
scanf("%s", regular_sequence);

//Here is the magic
char reversed_sequence[strlen(regular_sequence)];

void reverse_sequence(char* pattern, char* result) {
     int index = strlen(pattern) - 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pattern); i++) {
          result[index--] = pattern[i];
     }
}

reverse_sequence(regular_sequence, reversed_sequence);
printf("%s\n%s\n", regular_sequence, reversed_sequence);
```

Is it legal or is it an undefined behavior? Should I first copy the sequence and overwrite the copy?

PS - Sorry for possible typos, it isn't a copied code.

Comment: Once the memory is allocated, you can write to it in any way you wish

Comment: You forgot the null-termination of the `result`. Also you don't show how you put anything into `reversed_sequence`

Comment: you can just try ^_^

Comment: @piertoni this is certainly **NOT** the way to check for undefined behavior.

Comment: `sizeof(MAX_SEQ)` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: @dbush, what do you mean? I thought that size of char is 1 size_t EDIT I see it

Comment: Do you *really* want to declare `reversed_sequence` as an array of pointers to `char`? (Answer: NO)

Comment: `reversed_sequence` needs `strlen + 1` chars to hold the null at the end.

Comment: About the mentioned NULL terminator: do I have to use it manually at the end? printf() treat it as a normal sequence

Comment: Yes.  You need to add it.

Comment: Thank you! Another question, just to be sure: scanf() writes the string with the NULL terminator?

Comment: I really appreciate your tips, I forgot about the null terminator.

Comment: Yes, `scanf`'s `%s` writes the string with a null terminator. It is also dangerous if no maximum field width is specified (or if the specified maximum field width is greater than or equal to the size of the object where the string is being stored).

Comment: @IanAbbott Do you mean `scanf("%255s", regular_sequence)`?

Comment: Yes, after skipping initial whitespace characters, and if not at end of file, `scanf("%255s", regular_sequence);` will read at most 255 non-whitespace characters from the standard input stream to the array and append a null terminator character to the array. But if the return value of `scanf` indicates that no item was written to the array then it won't be null terminated.

Comment: With `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(pattern); i++) {`, code repeatedly runs down `pattern` to find its length.  It  assumes `result[index--] = pattern[i];` may have changed `pattern` as they are supplied pointers that _may_ overlap their data.  Better to find the length once.

Answer (score 4):

Once the memory is allocated properly, you can access it any way you want - from the beginning, from the middle or in zigzag pattern - at least, as far as compiler is concerned.

Note, that sequential access (from either ends) is usually faster due to various CPU caching techniques, so you should not employ zigzag access pattern unless you need to.

Having said that, you have an issue in your code:

```
malloc(sizeof(MAX_SEQ));
```

Doesn't do what you think it does, and instead is going to return the size of integer on your platform (i.e. 32 on x86_64). You want to drop `sizeof` and just use

```
malloc(MAX_SEQ);
```

P.S. Your code is clearly not [mcve]-compliant, so I was answering general question asked, rather than inspected provided snippet carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, much appreciated! Additionally, I have made an suggested edit to the post.